# Why do we need the "sweep" during mark-sweep Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose we are using the mark-sweep garbage collection algorithm, if we are able to flag memory allocations as "reclaimable", isn't that enough? Wouldn't the program know that "reclaimable" memory is basically unused memory that can be allocated when requested? What are the physical differences between a "reclaimable" chunk compared to an "unused" chunk as shown in this picture:
[image]

Comment: There is such a thing as a mark-and-don't-sweep collector. Did you read about it? Perhaps by comparing and contrasting those approaches you will find your answer

Comment: @Michael these “mark-and-don't-sweep collectors” only defer the sweeping to the point when the allocator has to search for the unmarked memory, which is technically the same as sweeping. Given that such algorithms are usually triggered by a failed allocation, so the allocator has to search for the first available chunk right after the marking, even the laziness is not necessarily given. So it’s just another name for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Marking** - During the mark phase all objects that are reachable from Java threads, native handles and other root sources are marked as alive, as well as the objects that are reachable from these objects and so forth. This process identifies and marks all objects that are still used, and the rest can be considered garbage.

**Sweeping** - During the sweep phase the heap is traversed to find the gaps between the live objects. These gaps are recorded in a free list and are made available for new object allocation.

**Unused vs Reclaimable space -**
Unused space is nothing but gaps between Alive blocks, these gaps are created due to garbage-collection of unused/reclaimable objects, compaction stage will move unused blocks to the end. Compare two diagrams from the posted image.

Comment: Why would it even need the sweep phase though? Couldn't it just build the free list while it's doing the mark phase?

Comment: @Ryn Mark phase is not as simple as seems, there are multiple sub-stages. Read here https://plumbr.io/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms-implementations/concurrent-mark-and-sweep

Comment: @Ryn how would you built a free list without knowing what to put into the list?

Answer (score 1):

The sweep step is just "another" way of delaying the stop-the-world event. Of course, in theory this is a good thing. *While* marking, also keep track of this "free" space, where dead objects have been identified. Thus, you can use that information from these lists when you allocate next time.

The thing is that the heap is not "compact" when you use `sweep` only, as such when there is not contiguous free space for allocation (based on these free lists information), a compaction phase will still be performed.

My last point is that `CMS` is deprecated, no one supports in, so understanding what it does might be interesting, but not really valuable; as other GC's do things differently.